# Force IntelliJ to use Maven artifact even if the module which produces the artifact is within the project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-15

I have project X containing modules Y and Z. Module Y relies on module Z (a third party library which I maintain a private fork of).

On a maven build module Z relocates it's very version specific packages to a seperate package e.g "com.example.z.internal.MyClass" becomes "com.example.z.internal.v23.MyClass".

When I didn't have module Z in my project it was fine as IntelliJ resolved to the maven dependency which contained the remappings however now I have module Z within the project, IntelliJ keeps being clever and using the module as the dependency not the artifact.

Is there a way to force IntelliJ to only use the artifact as the dependency?

Comment: remove the module from your project if you are not using it.

Comment: I am using it to maintain a private fork

Answer (score 0):

First option: remove the module of your project, intellij will not recompile all the time this module, and make a separated project for it when you want to modify this module.

Second option: build a released version X of your module (not a snapshot) and make your module to depend on this released version. Doing that, intellij will continue to make your fork, but under a snapshot version which you don't depend on.

Comment: There must be a better solution than that :/